# Linq Func Memory Leak

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, memory-leaks

[image: dotMemory]

I have a ViewModel that contains some code to maipulate collections. 
At first, i was thinking it was related to databinding leaks but it seems unrelated at all.
All I need to do is add a line of code like:

`MyTypes.Where(t => t.IsSelected).OrderBy(t => t.Item).Select(t => t.Item))`

This generates 3 references to the ViewModel and stops it from being collected.

Anyone explain whats happening?

Comment: Because linq functions return monads that reference your view model.  Nothing is done until you enumerate the results. Long story short, in order to not have this happen, call `ToArray()` at the end and keep THAT, not the IEnumerable<T>.  Long story long, you should go read up on how Linq works.  Not understanding can lead to performance issues and situations like this.

Comment: This example, the line was wrapped in a string.Join()
But normally, I always call ToList(). Yet Linq still keeps those func around.